# switch and response from httpsstatus

Tags: c#

I am trying to send a message through http request, which works fine. However I have an issue that if I get different response than   `case HttpStatusCode.OK:` then it always goes to the exception instead of going through the switch to the exact response so for example I get BadRequest as exception. How can I adjust my code for this to work through the switch or is there a better way to adjust this method and its response from web?

```cs
public void PushMessage(Message message, string number)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(_config.EndpointUrl);
        String encoded = HashifyService.GetToken(_config.AppSecret, _config.SALT, ReturnTimeSet());

        webRequest.Headers.Add("auth-token", encoded);
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";

        var requestMessage = PrepareMessage(message, number);
       
        using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            var jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestMessage);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonMessage);
            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            switch (response.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                       _succesHandler?.Invoke(number);
                    break;
                case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                    
                    break;
                case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
                     
                    break;
                case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
                    
                    break;
                case HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed:
                           
                    break;
                case HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout:
                          
                    break;
                case HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable:
                         
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: case HttpStatusCode.NotFound is not added.

Comment: How about using HttpClient instead?

Comment: I get the response like for example BadRequest in exception

Comment: HttpClient instead of HttpWebRequest? I am beginner with this so if that is better then I can try